# Game Center achievements global players percent not showing?

Tags: app-store, game-center

I recently created a new game and added achievements into the game for the first time however the % of global players stays at 0 and does not seem to be working.

My leaderboards work fine they update for players.

The achievements show in Game Center and when you achieve them they update in Game Center. It even shows if Game Center friends have completed them. The completition banners show in the game when they are achieved.

The game has been out for about 5 days now and every achievement (even the very easy ones I know others have accomplished shows 0% percent of all global players have earned this achievement).

I assume I coded this wrong but maybe there is something I need to do in App Store Connect that im missing? Maybe it takes so many days after launch? Maybe you need so many players? Not sure but any hints would be great.

Note: this game is written in Objective-C with not outside controls or external game engines.

I have tried toggling App Store connect settings. I initially assumed this wasnt working while I was in testflight because the game wasnt launched but this isnt the case.